# How do I not get frustrated when an inferior answer gets accepted?

Tags: discussion

I seem to work very hard at providing solutions to people. But my work goes without credit. I've seen other people's answers get up-voted when it's clear that my solution was faster, *and* I provided an explanation.

Why do some answers get up-voted, while better answers are sometimes ignored?

Comment: If you notice that the method in your answer has some superior characteristic compared with other answers posted do you state this to make it clear?

Comment: Don't answer crap questions. Better questions usually have authors that will read each answers and accept the best, while crap authors accept the first that *kinda works* without caring about efficiency or answer quality.

Comment: Just remind yourself that the question author is almost by definition the worst judge of answers. Otherwise he wouldn't have to ask the question.